# How to deploy custom policy in TFS from remote machine

Tags: tfs, tfs-2010

I am trying to deploy a custom policy in TFS2010. Since the deployment needs to be done in 2 steps,

> 1) update registry path
>   "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE/Software/Microsoft/VisualStudio/9.0/TeamFoundation/SourceControl/CheckinPolicies"
>
> 2) Paste the custom policy dlls in to
>   respective path on TFS server

Is there a way I can achieve this from a remote machine instead of logging on the TFS machine everytime just to deploy and test?

Answer (score 1):

This is totally possible, BUT you need the help of your TFS administrator **once**. He needs to activate the custom policy on your TFS project centrally, otherwise your check-in actions do not trigger the custom policy to be activated.

1. Create you custom policy.
2. Upload it to your projects version control tree according to: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/youhana/archive/2011/03/27/distributing-custom-check-in-policies-amp-wit-controls-using-team-members.aspx
3. Distribute TFS Powertools in your team to distribute and sync your custom policies.
4. Ask the TFS administrator to activate your custom policy.

Is this an acceptable scenario for your situation? You will never have to go to the TFS server to activate the custom policy anymore.